# Interactive Sorting for Table in SSRS at One Shot

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have 4 tables each table contains 10 columns. I would like to add interactive sorting for all columns. In order to do this, i have to each text box properties and select interactive sorting. By the way, is there any simple way to add interactive sorting for all columns in a table?

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to do it one at a time